# Is it possible to integrate youtube channel in android?

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-data-api, youtube-channels

I have the code for integrating YouTube videos in android.

What I want is to create a `listview` which lists different channels, and when user clicks on a channel it shows all the videos for that channel. By this way when a new video is loaded in a channel it will automatically be available in my app also.

Is it possible to integrate YouTube channel in android?

Comment: [Yes it is possible ...](https://developers.google.com/youtube/?hl=de)

Comment: @user2572585 I have used YouTubeAndroidPlayer api only for integration of youtube video..i want to integrate channel such that when a new video is loaded in a channel it will be automatically be available in my app..can u give me link of a tutorial of how to do channel integration?

Comment: @user2572585 I studied tutorials and found how to integrate playlist...but such integration will play all the videos from playlist back to back..I want to show user list of videos in playlist and then when user click on a video it plays that video...also i don't want to integrate each video separately..i want to integrate playlist such that when a new video is added to playlist it will be automatically be available in my app also

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes! Check out the Android Youtube Player API and the YouTube API.

Android Player:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

YouTube API:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/

YouTube Player API Sample: (sample folder in zip)
https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/

**EDIT**

The Data API lets you get information about videos in a channel, you can then use that info to construct your list of videos and update it accordingly.

For example, the following would retrieve the latest videos from a channel:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={your_key_here}&channelId={channel_id_here}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20
```

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer..I have used YouTubeAndroid Player api only for integration of youtube video..But can't find how to integrate channel..can u give me a example project or tutorial where channel integration of youtube is done?

Comment: In the YouTube Player API Demo App which contains many source codes,it only shows integration of youtube videos not channel..i want to integrate channel such that when a new video is loaded in a channel it will be automatically be available in my app

Comment: I studied tutorials and found how to integrate playlist...but such integration will play all the videos from playlist back to back..I want to show user list of videos in playlist and then when user click on a video it plays that video...also i don't want to integrate each video separately..i want to integrate playlist such that when a new video is added to playlist it will be automatically be available in my app also

Comment: So this is why I also linked the YouTube API, specifically what you would use is the YouTube Data API. With it you can make a request to get a JSON object back with a list of videos in a channel that contains data about the video, including id's and thumbnails. You can use this to construct a list of the videos, once the user clicks on one of those you can use the id that you got back and pass it to the actual player. To update the videos in the list you can just make the request again and see if there are any new id's in the list that are not already in your app.

Comment: Thanku for the answer..+1 to it..i'll try using JSON parsing for the url given by u..

Comment: the demo app link is not available anymore. could this be updated with a more recent link?

Comment: @Phantomazi I updated the link to the newest demo app download.