# youtube api show channel videos android

Tags: java, android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I looked all over but cant find how to call up a list of videos into an android app. so far i am using the sample, but that wont do any good if i upload a video because then i would have to send an update every time. Part of Sample code:

```
  `   List<VideoEntry> list = new ArrayList<VideoEntry>();
  list.add(new VideoEntry("KitPvP(Where I die alot(lol))", "Ji0yzF8boGg"));
  list.add(new VideoEntry("GMail Tap", "1KhZKNZO8mQ"));
  list.add(new VideoEntry("Chrome Multitask", "UiLSiqyDf4Y"));
  list.add(new VideoEntry("Google Fiber", "re0VRK6ouwI"));
  list.add(new VideoEntry("Autocompleter", "blB_X38YSxQ"));
  list.add(new VideoEntry("GMail Motion", "Bu927_ul_X0"));
  list.add(new VideoEntry("exampleA", "exampleB"));`
```

need a way to get exampleA and B

Comment: Hello Moocow9m, I have an app that uses Youtube API to play Youtube videos.  I do need to update the APK if I want to change which videos are included.  Are you wanting allow the user to upload videos to YouTube?   And/OR are you wanting to allow the user to search for videos on Youtube?

Comment: neither. it is a one to two channel app only. @joshgoldeneagle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to interact with YouTube you have to use the YouTube Data API.
As I understand it, at the moment you're using only the YouTube Player API to play videos.

In order to get new video IDs (and everything else) from YouTube you have to use this: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/

Comment: I'm Trying to get channels using the URL https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?key="+Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY but getting No peer certificate exception.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for adding a channel subscription for your Android App.  It prompts the user for a Youtube Channel ID, and subscribes the user to that channel if it is a valid Channel ID.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java#add_a_channel_subscription

There are also some Youtube API code samples here for working with channels:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/

You may also want to see this topic "Is it possible to integrate Youtube channel into Android?"

[Is it possible to integrate youtube channel in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549908/is-it-possible-to-integrate-youtube-channel-in-android)