# Get selected video in Youtube Intent or Youtube Player

Tags: android, android-intent, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Hey everyone, i would like to get the link of an selected video in an "Youtube Intent"

I've this actually ;

```
Intent intent = YouTubeIntents.createChannelIntent (SelectDocFragment.this.getActivity(), "PitbullVEVO");
            startActivity(intent);
```

I would like an startActivityForResult, and the result should be "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ODh6hSZBJqY" which is the youtube that i selected in my YoutubeIntent.

i've tried to achieve this with an Youtube Player Api, and load my channel :

```
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                youTubePlayer.cuePlaylist("PLRX442jA-zGKxR-wAfC_xUvpZX1Rh0usm");
```

I'm able to get the current Video with :

```
public void onLoaded(String mVideoId) {
                        String url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + mVideoId;
                    }
```

But, youTubePlayer.cuePlaylist or youTubePlayer.loadVideo are not able to load an channel where i could selected any videos.

Similarly to this topic : [Is it possible to integrate youtube channel in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549908/is-it-possible-to-integrate-youtube-channel-in-android)

It is possible to get this with YoutubeIntent ?

**EDIT** :
 I would like this in my android APP, and here i choose the video that i will display after, i just want the link of the video selected by the user.

[image]

Comment: Yes it is able. You need to make a request to YouTube Api either by `channel id` or `location` or `genre` etc. to get JSON data. Then you can parse JSON into your app to pick and play particular video. And I think you don't need full url just `ID` of video like above: `ODh6hSZBJqY`

Comment: I would like to display the channel in my android App, to make the user able to choose the video, not to display only the video

Comment: Then this is your answer: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={your_key_here}&channelId={channel_id_here}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20`

Comment: I know this, this is not my answer, what i want is to display the channel in my app, and get the link of the selected video.
See the EDIT :)

Comment: As I said you need to make request to YouTube API to get response which will contain JSON data, using url which I provided to you putting your `key` and `channel id`. JSON data will contain image of each video, title, description, url etc all information that are shown on image. Then you can parse data into `listview` or `recyclerview` and show in app. You are sure to know this? Or feel free to find another solution. Let me know when you succeed.

Comment: Do you know a tutorial to create this listview ?
And, is it possible to update it when a new video is added ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said Yupi : [Get selected video in Youtube Intent or Youtube Player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47753405/get-selected-video-in-youtube-intent-or-youtube-player?noredirect=1#comment82468156_47753405) 
We have to request the Youtube APi to get a JSON and then parse it.

To do this, i've found a very useful tutorial here :
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1214971/Youtube-channel-integration-in-Android-using

For anyone who want to do the same :)

Here is a demo : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GJMdgwvrR_Y